# Execution of sql query

Tags: mysql

I am geting some problem with the execution of query to this problem
Write a query to display the names of users who have raised queries, sorted in order. 
My query is:

```
select name
from user
where id IN (
    select user_id 
    from query
    where id In (select parent_id from query)
)
order by name
```

where query table has one to many relation with itself with columns

```
id BIGINT(20),content VARCHAR(255),date DATETIME,
parent_id BIGINT(20),user_id BIGINT(20)
```

I am having another query related to answered query for this same table.Can some one provide the query?

Comment: `query` is a reserved word in mysql; don't name a table that: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this query,

```
SELECT name
FROM user
WHERE id IN (
            SELECT a.user_id 
            FROM query a
            JOIN query b ON(a.id = b.parent_id)
        )
ORDER BY name
```